# How to make box2d bodies block each other but not push each other?

Tags: box2d, movement

I want to use box2D to create a movement system for an RTS game.  How can I make bodies block the movement of other bodies while preventing these bodies from pushing each other?

Comment: Have you tried increasing friction and/or changing the mass of the bodies you don't want to be "pushed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want standard collision detection, but a custom collision response.  [Sensors (Fixtures subsection 6.3)](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972) provide that functionality.

1. Disable the default collision (use static bodies, filtering, etc.)
2. Attach a sensor and implement a custom collision response